# Silverlight.Binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, prism

I have a view model with a property defined as:

```
private SomeEntity currentEntity;
public SomeEntity CurrentEntity
{
    get { return currentEntity; }
    set { currentEntity = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentEntity); }
}
```

In a view I defined a binding to `SomeEntity.Name` property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentEntity.Name }" />
```

This works. But when I wrote this in another way this doesn't work, `CurrentEntity`  is always null:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {                    
        return CurrentEntity != null ? CurrentEntity.Name : null;
    }
    set
    {
        CurrentEntity.Name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentEntity);
    }
}

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name }" />
```

Do you have any ideas why? Is there any workaround?

Comment: you had to create property for Name and add to RaisePropertyChange for Name

Comment: I don't know your reasons for using this pattern, but it is horrible. Why not just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `SomeEntity`?

Comment: @Martin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912412/how-to-bind-a-single-view-to-multiple-viewmodels-properly that's what I am trying to solve. And I am trying to implement MVVM with Prism library. The view model inherits from NotificationObject.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RaisePropertyChanged( () => Name)`

Internally, the binding subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
When binding to the "Name" property, it will check if the Property parameter of the event arguments equals the name of the property it binds to (i.e.: PropertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName == "Name"). If not it will ignore the notification.

Comment: looks like I have to add 'RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentEntity);' and 'RaisePropertyChanged( () => Name);' to both CurrentEntity and Name setters. Am I right?

Comment: That would depend on what the exact bindings are used for, but for the binding you've shown, just raising the Name property changed would suffice. If that doesn't work, then you'll have to show some more code and XAML so I can see exactly what binds to what, and what the DataContext of those bindings is.

Comment: to be more correct I have to subscribe to CurrentEntity PropertyChanged and call 'RaisePropertyChanged( () => Name);' in handler

Comment: No, that's not the way to go. Show actual code and XAML, and we can probably figure it out.

Comment: the initial problem and code samples are provided in this question, maybe you can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912412/how-to-bind-a-single-view-to-multiple-viewmodels-properly

Answer (score 0):

I think you had to create property for Name and add to RaisePropertyChange for Name